# Copy rows between two strings based on search condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have to search column B for a certain string and return a specific range of cells for all occurrences of the string in the file. I have code which searches and finds all occurrences of the string but have difficulty with copying into a new sheet the specific range of cells between `Path` and `Owner`. The catch is that the row numbers between `Path` and `Owner` are dynamic.

**Excel structure**

[image: SO25755876 question example]
(including expected results for search string `Kevin`).

**Macro**

```
Sub FindString()
Dim intS As Integer
Dim rngC As Range
Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim wSht As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

intS = 1
Set wSht = Worksheets("Search Results")
strToFind = Range("I3").Value 'This is where I obtain the string to be searched

With ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B999999")
    Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = rngC.Address
            Do
              (   
                'need help to find copy rows from column B based on values in column A
              )
               intS = intS + 1
               Set rngC = .FindNext(rngC)
            Loop While Not rngC Is Nothing And rngC.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

Please help me or guide me as I'm a newbie to Excel.

Comment: I cannot understand the structure of Excel.  "Path: D:\Pictures Owner: Mark User: David Joe Kevin" for example, what are data of column A  ,column B , column C and so on, respectively?

Comment: First in your search method, you need to change to `Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart, After:=rngC)` as you get error when rngC is Nothing. When you found it, add a loop to check `.Offset(r,-1).Value` equals "Path:", then copy the value of `.Offset(r,0)`. `r` is type **Long** and starts from 1.

Comment: @Fumu Hope your concern is addressed now, thanks to the edits by the moderator. @ PatricK -Thank you for your guidance. I will try your suggestion and post the code if I am able to implement it successfully.

Comment: Now that screenshot is there, the `r` in my previous comment should not start at 1 if the Path is above searched result. Instead, `r` starts from -1 and then -2, -3 etc. You may also want a variable to locate the row of Owner as well

Comment: @PatricK Thank you for your help. I'm getting a type mismatch error when I add After:=rngC in the search method.
As per your suggestion, I am able to find the cell next to path by using a Do Until loop and by decrementing the value of r. Can you shed some light on how I can copy the dynamic range between path and owner? I understand that the reason why you suggested to have a variable for owner is for the same purpose, it would be great if you can help me with a little more detail on that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will display the paths found (variable **sPath**), this is untested:

```
Sub FindString()
    'Dim intS As Integer
    Dim rngC As Range
    Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
    Dim wSht As Worksheet, lRowPath As Long, lRowOwner As Long, i As Long, sPath As String

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'intS = 1
    Set wSht = Worksheets("Search Results")
    strToFind = Range("I3").Value 'This is where I obtain the string to be searched

    'With ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B999999")
    With ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
        Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rngC.Address
            Do
                ' Find the "Path:" above the found cell, note that offset too much is not handled: Cells(-1,1)
                i = -1
                Do Until InStr(1, rngC.Offset(i, -1).Value, "Path", vbTextCompare) > 0
                    i = i - 1
                Loop
                lRowPath = rngC.Row + i
                ' Find the Owner row above the found cell
                i = -1
                Do Until InStr(1, rngC.Offset(i, -1).Value, "Owner", vbTextCompare) > 0
                    i = i - 1
                Loop
                lRowOwner = rngC.Row + i
                'need help to find copy rows from column B based on values in column A
                sPath = ""
                For i = lRowPath To lRowOwner - 1
                    sPath = sPath & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value ' <-- Update
                Next
                Debug.Print "Searching " & strToFind; " --> " & sPath
                'intS = intS + 1
                Set rngC = .Find(what:=strToFind, After:=rngC, LookAt:=xlPart)
            Loop Until rngC.Address = FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason SPath is null, I was trying to select the rows defined by Spath in the following way to the another sheet but even that doesn't work. ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lRowPath & "  : " & " B " & lRowOwner).Select.

Comment: sorry, it should have been `sPath = sPath & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value`

Comment: Glad to hear that @Ajay, please close the question by marking this as answer.

Comment: Thank you.Will close the question, please give me some time to understand the alternate approach explained here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load everything to memory first, then do your searches and manipulations.

You could use a user-defined type to store info about your paths:

```
Type PathPermissionsType
    pth As String
    owner As String
    users As Dictionary
End Type
```

Note: to use `Dictionary` you need to go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>><kbd>References</kbd> and set a checkmark next to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

You can load all your info using something like this:

```
Function LoadPathPermissions() As PathPermissionsType()
    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim iPath As Long
    Dim nPath As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim vHeaders As Variant
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim pathPermissions() As PathPermissionsType

    Set rngHeaders = Range("A1:A12") 'or wherever
    Set rngData = rngHeaders.Offset(0, 1)
    'Load everything to arrays
    vHeaders = rngHeaders.Value
    vData = rngData.Value
    nRow = UBound(vData, 1)

    nPath = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngHeaders, "Path:")
    ReDim pathPermissions(1 To nPath)
    iRow = 1
    'Look for first "Path:" header.
    Do Until InStr(vHeaders(iRow, 1), "Path") <> 0
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
    'Found "Path:" header.
    For iPath = 1 To nPath
        With pathPermissions(iPath)
            'Now look for "Owner:" header, adding to the path until it is found.
            Do Until InStr(vHeaders(iRow, 1), "Owner") <> 0
                .pth = .pth & vData(iRow, 1)
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Loop
            'Found "Owner:" header.
            .owner = vData(iRow, 1)
            '"User:" header is on next row:
            iRow = iRow + 1
            'Now add users to list of users:
            Set .users = New Dictionary
            Do Until InStr(vHeaders(iRow, 1), "Path") <> 0
                .users.Add vData(iRow, 1), vData(iRow, 1)
                iRow = iRow + 1
                If iRow > nRow Then Exit Do ' End of data.
            Loop
        End With
    Next iPath
    LoadPathPermissions = pathPermissions
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Dim pathPermissions() As PathPermissionsType
pathPermissions = LoadPathPermissions()
```

Then to get an array containing the paths for a given user:

```
Function GetPathsForUser(ByVal user As String, pathPermissions() As PathPermissionsType) As String()
    Dim iPath As Long
    Dim iPathsWithPermission As Long
    Dim nPathsWithPermission As Long
    Dim pathsWithPermission() As String
    For iPath = LBound(pathPermissions) To UBound(pathPermissions)
        If pathPermissions(iPath).users.Exists(user) Then nPathsWithPermission = nPathsWithPermission + 1
    Next iPath
    ReDim pathsWithPermission(1 To nPathsWithPermission)
    iPathsWithPermission = 0
    For iPath = LBound(pathPermissions) To UBound(pathPermissions)
        If pathPermissions(iPath).users.Exists(user) Then
            iPathsWithPermission = iPathsWithPermission + 1
            pathsWithPermission(iPathsWithPermission) = pathPermissions(iPath).pth
        End If
    Next iPath
    GetPathsForUser = pathsWithPermission
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Dim pathPermissions() As PathPermissionsType
Dim pathsWithPermission() As String
pathPermissions = LoadPathPermissions()
pathsWithPermission = GetPathsForUser("Kevin", pathPermissions)
```

Now `pathsWithPermission` is an array containing the paths for which Kevin is listed as user. Note that I haven't dealt with edge cases, like if Kevin is a not a user for any paths, etc. Up to you to do that.

Finally you can write the contents of that array to your sheet.

Comment: Your suggestion looks great, being a newbie, please give me some time to understand and customize your code to suit my needs. I am attempting to implement this on a file which has 999999 rows. Will update once I see the results

Comment: For such large datasets, this approach will be *much* quicker than doing manipulations directly in the sheet.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds very silly, but I'm having little trouble understanding the flow of this code. I can learn it by debugging it stepwise, can you pleasenhelp me execute this for the sample user kevin in this file? (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xeiboyhcmesd1mu/Book1.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: I gave you an example usage. Step through it in debug mode, [as instructed here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx), and you will understand it.